# Trigger to insert a row into another table on delete

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger which will insert a row with all columns into another table:

This is what I've got so far, but it isn't working:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER item_deleted_move AFTER DELETE ON item
begin
insert into item_deleted (val1, val2, ...) values (old.val1, old.val2, ...);
end$$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The root of the error is that you miss required `FOR EACH ROW` clause for [`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html) statement.

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER item_deleted_moved 
AFTER DELETE ON item
FOR EACH ROW -- You missed this part
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO item_deleted(val1, val2, ...) VALUES (old.val1, old.val2, ...);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now if you don't do anything else in your trigger except for inserting you can simplify it by not using `BEGIN ... END` block. In that case you don't need to change delimiters.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER item_deleted_moved 
AFTER DELETE ON item
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO item_deleted(val1, val2, ...) VALUES (old.val1, old.val2, ...);
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e50d7d/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

You changed delimiter to `$$` but at the end of the insert you are using `;`